# Finding out loading time of webelements in a webpage using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, webpage-rendering, response-time, qwebelement

I have a webpage(HTML 5) in which there are 4 charts, each of which taking different time to load once the static content in the page comes up. The Loading is shown in the webpage using a 'rendering' circle image for all the 4 charts. I want to find out how much time each of the charts were showing the 'rendering' circle. Please help me in getting a solution using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

It is the crude way but it must work.

Create a infinite loop with 1 second wait and in each iteration check if the chart is loaded or not. Once all four charts are loaded or if you have timeout value come out of loop. 
In this case there is possibility of error of 1 sec. If your chart is loading fast or want to reduce the margin of error reduce the wait from 1 sec to 100msec.

Pseudo code :[May use this to write better code]

```
boolean[] chartLoaded = {false,false,false,false};
int[] chartLoadTime = {0,0,0,0};
int counter = 0;
while(counter < 100)
{
    counter++;
    if(isLoaded(chart1))
    {
         chartLoaded[0] = true;
         chartLoadTime[0]++; 
    }
    //Do this for other three charts also
    if(chartLoaded[0] && chartLoaded[1] && chartLoaded[2] && chartLoaded[3])
        break;

}
```